# Kaк установить Linux без потери данных

Tags: linux, windows, kali-linux

Хочу поставить себе вместо windows, linux(kali linux). Скажите пожалуйста, как сделать это не потеряв данные на диске D? Спасибо всем)

Comment: Kali - утилитарный дистрибутив, почему вместо Windows? Просто подготовьте/освободите/выделите ему партицию и ставьте в неё... Вообще, проще всего её держать на Live-USB...

Comment: Прикреп к верхнему комментарию: ссылочка, как это сделать - http://startubuntu.ru/?p=104328. Причём данные на диске D будут видны с Linux'a.

Comment: @vp_arth у меня есть live usb, но место на флешке заканчивается

Comment: Как бы вы его не ставили, но Linux должен работать на файловой системе, поддерживающей права доступа unix. И разделы windows к таким файловым системам не относятся. так что в любом случае на существующий D установить вы его не сможете. Необходимо освободить место под новый раздел диска

Comment: Согласен с первым комментом - этот дистрибутив не предназначен для замены винды. Если вы новичёк в линуксе, начните с убунты, минта или манджары.

Comment: Если я правильно вас понял, то на раздел диска с меткой С у вас установлена винда, а на разделе D лежат ваши данные. В таком случае (если вы заменяете винду на линукс), то вам достаточно при установке дистрибутива переформатировать раздел С из NTFS в EXT4, указав на нём корневую точку монтирования, а D примонтировать без форматирования или вообще не трогать.

Comment: 1. Сделать бэкап диска Д. 2. Установить линукс на диск С, не трогая диск Д. 3. Радоваться, что линукс поставился, данные не пропали и бэкап не понадобился.

Comment: *место на флешке заканчивается* — так вставьте вторую.

Comment: Зацепил "мистер робот"?

Comment: Зачем ставить Kali на диск o_O

Comment: Вообще мой опыт с kali ничего хорошего не показал. В 50% случаев она на установится, а если и установится, то ничего хорошего не будет. Kali linux ни в коем случае не годится в основную ОС. Если прям хочется установить linux, то лучше поставьте Ubuntu или наподобие. Kali лучше использовать только на виртуалке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Раньше тоже "парился этой фигней"... **Не нужно так делать!** Не выделяйте никакие партиции и не мучайтесь с загрузкой и другими проблемами...

Используете виртуальные машины (hyper-v, virtual box, ...) или вообще отдельные диски (физически отдельные).  Купите отдельный диск и установите на него. Я понимаю чуть дороже и некоторый шок, типа - "зачем?". Но никой "боли" больше... И не нужно никаких манипуляций с критически важными данными.

Чем больше будете набираться опыта тем яснее будет картина и то, как лучше.    **Для обучения и тестирования лучше использовать виртуальные машины**.

Comment: Да, так уже давно и сделал, установил на второй диск!